# Write data to file with tabs

Tags: r, paste

I have files with information separated by tabs. I would like to append calculated values to each specific files and have tried to get the same format using the 'paste' command, but it separates a line instead of a tab. 
The file looks like (with [tab] representing a tab):

```
text[tab]=[tab]value
text[tab]=[tab]value
```

Creating a single line with tabs does not work using paste as it will print \t:

```
conv <- paste("conversion", "=", (y[,2]/90.6),sep="\t")
```

But if I try to add tabs later using:

```
conv <- paste("conversion", "=", (y[,2]/90.6),sep=",")
write(conv, file = "data.dat", append = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

"conv" comes on separate lines:

```
text[tab]=[tab]value
text[tab]=[tab]value
conversion
=
11.7991169977925
```

instead of in tabs (what I want):

```
text[tab]=[tab]value
text[tab]=[tab]value
conversion[tab]=[tab]11.80
```

I am sure there must be a very easy solution to this but I simply couldn't find out. Thanks!

Comment: Have to ask: are you sure you want to do this? Typical text files separate data with tabs (or other delimiters), not relationships, i.e. your "=" sign.  I suspect that anyone who wants to make use of your output file will not want tab-separated "="signs in it either.  Why not just create column names, e.g., "Name" and "Value" ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The reason why I do this is because the data files are associated with tracking software I use and I want to keep this information associated with the files. Thanks for your comment though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this implements what you want using Arun's suggestion.  Although, I agree with Carl Witthoft's comment.

```
y1 <- c(10, 20)
y2 = c(100,200)
y <- data.frame(y1,y2)
colnames(y) <- c('y1','y2')

y3 <- (y[,2]/90.6)

df <- data.frame('conversion', '=', y3)
colnames(df) <- c('t1', 't1', 'y3')
df

write.table(df, file = "c:/users/Mark W Miller/simple R Programs/my.data.txt", 
            append = TRUE, sep = "\t", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

The output file is:

```
conversion  =   1.1037527593819
conversion  =   2.2075055187638
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution was indeed to use a dataframe and 'write.table' instead of 'write' while including 'row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE'